# How to use rild command

Tags: android, ril

In android and under /system/bin/  there is a  rild command which should be used as following:

```
   rild -l   <ril impl library>   [--<args for impl library>]
```

However I don't know how to use the command and how could control the baseband modem?

Any reference about  this command?

Best regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My system is android ics. The following command works fine in my system. The libreference-ril.so is the RIL library. The ttyUSB2 is the device node created by drivers.

```
/system/bin/rild -l /system/lib/libreference-ril.so -- -d /dev/ttyUSB2
```

The rild is the ril daemon, and it is usually registered as service in init.rc as shown the following.

```
service ril-daemon /system/bin/rild -l /system/lib/libreference-ril.so -- -d /dev/ttyUSB2
class main
socket rild stream 660 root radio
socket rild-debug stream 660 radio system
user root
group radio cache inet misc audio sdcard_rw log
```

Comment: it seems that we can dynamically load ril-daemon during android runtime using rild command!!

Comment: How do you dynamically load it at runtime?